# How to change backend folder name in Yii2

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, yii2

I am trying to change folder name from *backend* to *admin* so that users trying to use the default link would run into a vacuum.

Is it possible with a `.htaccess` file or can Yii support me to do so?

Comment: What you are trying to do here is called [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). Better protect your backend with a strong password.

Comment: I am trying to hide my backend folder name

Comment: @AliRaza - Even more important here is that an attacker will use `admin` *before* using `backend`. That said, should your backend not work through a controller? If you are using a full-stack framework, I don't see why you should have a folder for your backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /path/backend    http://www.cyourdomain.com/path/admin
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to update your `config/main.php` with an alias and change the id and controllerNamespace:

```
return [
    'id' => 'app-admin',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'admin\controllers',
    'aliases' => [
        '@admin' => '@common/../admin',
],
```

Then you would have to update all the namespaces and class calls around the application to correspond with the new name.

That being said, as the others have pointed out in the comments, I'm not sure there's any point to all this.

First off all, you can point any subdomain to your `/web` directories.

Secondly, as pointed out in the comments - `admin` is more likley to be guessed than `backend`.

And third (and maybe the most important) if the attacker has access to your structure below the htdocs - a renaming would not help you much!